# Vespa.ai storage 0 down

Tags: kubernetes, vespa

I recently start using vespa, and I deployed a cluster on Kubernetes and index some data.. but toda one of storage shows down on "vespa-get-cluster-state":

[vespa@vespa-0 /]$ vespa-get-cluster-state
Cluster feature:
feature/storage/0: down
feature/storage/1: up
feature/storage/2: up
feature/distributor/0: up
feature/distributor/1: up
feature/distributor/2: up

I don't know what is this storage... this cluster had 2 content nodes, 2 containers nodes and 1 master.

How see logs and diagnostic why this down.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: This question would work better on the [Vespa Slack](http://slack.vespa.ai/), or as a [github issue](https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues).

According to the message you shared you have 3 content nodes (each have a "storage service responsible for storing the data, and a "distributor" service, responsible for managing a subset of the data space. The reason the node is down is not included in this message but you can find it by running `vespa-logfmt -l warning,error` on your admin node.